# Error in Xml to List code. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is a snippet of my xml,

```
<e80:td941Grp>
<e80:td941KeyGrp>
<e80:membExchIdCod>XX445678</e80:membExchIdCod>
<e80:membExchIdNam>XX44567899123</e80:membExchIdNam>
</e80:td941KeyGrp>
<e80:td941Rec>
<e80:prodId>5AB</e80:prodId>
<e80:quoReqTot>0</e80:quoReqTot>
<e80:dCutLim>150</e80:dCutLim>
<e80:goodQuoReqResp>0</e80:goodQuoReqResp>
<e80:quoReqViol>0</e80:quoReqViol>
<e80:shtQuoPct>0.00</e80:shtQuoPct>
<e80:valQuoReqViol>0</e80:valQuoReqViol>
<e80:valQuoReqTot>0</e80:valQuoReqTot>
<e80:valGoodQuoReqResp>0</e80:valGoodQuoReqResp>
<e80:violPct>0.00</e80:violPct>
</e80:td941Rec>
```

and this is my code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public class td941Rec
{


    private string _prodID;
    private string _qouReqTot;
    private string _dCutLim;
    private string _goodQuoRepResp;
    private string _quoReqViol;
    private string _shtQuoPct;
    private string _valQuoReqViol;
    private string _ValQuoRepTot;
    private string _valGoodQuoReqResp;
    private string _violPct;


    public string prodID { get; set; }
    public string qouReqTot { get; set; }
    public string dCutLim { get; set; }
    public string goodQuoRepResp { get; set; }
    public string quoReqViol { get; set; }
    public string shtQuoPct { get; set; }
    public string valQuoReqViol { get; set; }
    public string ValQuoRepTot { get; set; }
    public string valGoodQuoReqResp { get; set; }
    public string violPct { get; set; }

}

public class td941Grp
{
    private string _td941;
    public string td941 { get { return _td941; } set { _td941 = value; } }

    public List<td941Rec> dataList = new List<td941Rec>();
}


class QoutePerformance
{



    public void xmltoExcel()
    {
        string xmlDoc  =        @"........xxxxx.xml";

        XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(xmlDoc);

        td941Grp objtd941 = new td941Grp();

List<td941Grp> listtd941 = (from _td941 in xdoc1.Element("e80:td941")
.Elements("e80:td941Grp")
select new td941Grp
{
td941 = _td941.Element("e80:td941Grp").Value,dataList = (from _record in _td941.
Element("e80:td941Grp").Elements("e80:td941Rec")
select new td941Rec
{
   prodID = _td941.Element("prodID").Value,
   qouReqTot = _td941.Element("qouReqTot").Value,


 }).ToList()


  }).ToList();







    }
```

I get the error XmlException was unhandled "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."

Im relatively newb to c# but an total novice at xml so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can't remember the API well enough to answer but the `e80` is a namespace rather than part of the element name so you'll need to create an element called `td941` in the namespace `e80`. I can't remember how to do this but it might be a point to start searching yourself before others answer. :)

Comment: Why are you declaring both `_prodID` and `prodID`? If they are the same thing, get rid of one of them (probably `_prodID`).

Comment: Don't update the title to the next problem. Your new problem is one of the most asked questions here so research it properly. If necessary, post a new question and be sure to include the full exception stacktrace and link it to your code.

Comment: @Timujin, please consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net

Comment: @Hank. Thanks. apologies for changing the title, thought it easier to save time...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `.Element("e80:td941")`

Instead, use an XNamespace:

```
XNamespace nsE80 = xmlDoc.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("e80");

... .Element(nsE80 + "td941")
```

Comment: Thanks. That got rid of that error, now got other problems. :-)

Comment: i now get a NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." bit confused now...